# what type of interface use to connect to mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie and I would know which is the best way to interact with mysql db through php?what kind of available interface is better to using? mysqli o pdo?

Comment: When you ask question, So shows a _suggestion_ list. After you post it SO shows _related_ questions. Did you ever see those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between mysql,mysqli and pdo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a gander at [What is the difference between MySQL, MySQLi and PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)

Accepted answer copied in below, for people who don't have a mouse to click links with :)

---

`Author: Matthew Flaschen`

There are (more than) three popular ways to use MySQL from PHP.

1. The mysql functions are procedural and use manual escaping.
2. mysqli is a replacement for the mysql functions, with object-oriented and procedural versions. It has support for prepared statements.
3. PDO (PHP Data Objects) is a general database abstraction layer with support for MySQL among many other databases. It provides prepared statements, and significant flexibility in how data is returned.

I would recommend using PDO with prepared statements. It is a well-designed API and will let you more easily move to another database (including any that supports ODBC) if necessary.

Comment: Nope, I'll go Google that. I mainly just get on here and answer stuff, there's a fair bit of SO stuff I don't know.

Comment: @Joe true.. but it's fair to say that the chances of PDO being introduced in some form or another on stackoverflow is pretty high. If someone asked a simple `strtotime` question would you just assume that a basic date-formatting question had NEVER been asked before? At the same time you've never seen a question closed or flagged as a dupe before?

Comment: I've seen closed questions, I've seen people answer with "Possible duplicate: [link]" (which is essentially what I just did), and if I take the approach of "It's probably been asked before" I may as well just go round saying "Duplicate" on the vast majority of questions. I've tried to be helpful by giving the link to the duplicate which had a good answer, and copying in the answer for lazy people.

Comment: @MikeB its my mistake. I didn't read your comment earlier. Now I understand. :) Now deleting my comments. Thanks :)