# Is this SQL query safe from injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, security

The code below is written in php:

```
$user = addslashes($_POST['user']);
$pwd = addslashes($_POST['pwd']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE UserName='$user' AND Password=PASSWORD('$pwd')";
```

the query will then be sent to mysql
Is there anything more I need to take care of?

Please point out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

The reason is that while a single quote `'` is not the only char that break a sql query, quotes are the only chars escaped by `addslashes()`.

**Better**: use `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'], $conn);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd'], $conn);

$query = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE UserName='$user' AND Password=PASSWORD('$pwd')";
```

**Best**: use PDO and prepared statements

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE UserName=':user' AND Password=PASSWORD(':pass')");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated.  They shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: That makes sense. It could be better if you can show a simple example of how injection to that code is possible

Comment: Here's a good example of how you can inject after addslashes is run: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 5):

No it's not safe, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) at ***minimum***:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);
```

And for **better** security go for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

***Best** Options:*

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

You may ask which one to choose, check out:

- [What is difference between mysql,mysqli and pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I cannot accept all replies as answers.

Answer (score 3):

No. You should **not** be using `addslashes()` to escape your data. That's been obsolete for *years*. You should be either:

- using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as a replacement
- using prepared statements with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Plus using MySQL's `Password()` function is also poor pracdtive. Use hashes with salts. Bcrypt is my recommendation. Also, check out [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 2):

Protecting against SQL injection is easy:

**Filter your data.**

This cannot be overstressed. With good data filtering in place, most security concerns are mitigated, and some are practically eliminated.

**Quote your data.**

If your database allows it (MySQL does), put single quotes around all values in your SQL statements, regardless of the data type.

**Escape your data.**

Sometimes valid data can unintentionally interfere with the format of the SQL statement itself. Use `mysql_escape_string()` or an escaping function native to your particular database. If there isn't a specific one, `addslashes()` is a good last resort.

Read more: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/3.html#3.2