# What is the difference between bind_param() and bindParam()?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm confused finding the difference between `bind_param()` and `bindParam()` as both are supported in PHP5 but one takes type as the first parameter and other takes a placeholder. Can someone give me an example of when to use one or the other?

Comment: which class contains `bind_param`? Current PDO doesn't look like it contains a `bind_param` method http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 14):

bind_param is a method on mysqli_stmt:

[mysqli_stmt - bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

bindParam is a method on PDOStatement:

[PDOStatement - bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

The difference?

- mysqli is a replacement for the deprecated mysql functions
- PDO (PHP Data Objects) is a general database abstraction layer with support for MySQL, but also many other databases (sqlite, postgresql, oracle,...).

For more info look at this:

[What is the difference between mysql, mysqli and pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)

Answer (score 5):

bind_param() is mysqli and bindParam() is PDO. Apples and Oranges.