# Can't store data in Database(PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, store

yesterday it took me nearly 4 hours to fix this php code.. im a beginner in php, so i don't have the experience to find the bug in this code.

the .php give me no errors, i also wrote this two lines at the begin:

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`´
`ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`

**and this is my php code:**

```
//Variablen zuweisen
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$betreff = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'betreff');
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message');

/*if (($vorname == "") OR ($nachname == "") OR($email == "")) {
        echo "Fehler: Eintrag unvollständig.";
        die; 
}*/

    //Verbindung herstellen
    $datenbank = mysql_connect("*******", "****", "*****") or die ("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ".mysql_error());
    $verbunden = mysql_select_db("4109932db1") or die ("Datenbank nicht gefunden oder fehlerhaft");

    //Daten in DB speichern
    $sql_befehl = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Contact_Requests (Name,Mail,Betreff,Message) VALUES ($name, $email, $betreff, $message");

    if($sql_befehl)
    { echo "Ihr Eintrag wurde hinzugefügt."; }

    //Verbindung beenden
    mysql_close($datenbank);
```

**this is my html code, i have a formular and this should send data to my php file (insert.php)**

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:*</td><td><input type="text" value="Name" id="name" onfocus="nameDel();" onblur="nameSet();" name="name" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Mail:*</td><td><input type="email" value="E-Mail" id="email" onfocus="emailDel();" onblur="emailSet();" name="email"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Betreff:*</td><td><input type="text" value="Grund der Nachricht" id="regard" onfocus="regardDel();" onblur="regardSet();" name="betreff"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>
                    Nachricht:*<br><textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="msg" onfocus="msgDel();" onblur="msgSet();" name="message">Deine Nachricht</textarea>
                </p>    
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Senden" id="send" onclick="sendContact();">
                </p>
            </form>
```

Comment: All you have for code is a form (with no JS btw). Where is the SQL?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: omg i dumbass i forgot the php file omg sry

Comment: also share your insertion query script... ?

Comment: so now i also post the php script and the problem is the data wouldnt be stored in the database

Comment: @Nico It is never good to post database access data..... you should change your password ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is what is affected:

```
VALUES ($name, $email, $betreff, $message")
```

The variables need to be wrapped in quotes:

```
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$betreff', '$message')
```

Your double quote at the end is not in the right spot because you forgot a closing bracket `)`

```
(Name,Mail,Betreff,Message) VALUES ($name, $email, $betreff, $message");
                                                                     ^
```

which should be

```
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$betreff', '$message')");
```

The affected line should now look like:

```
$sql_befehl = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Contact_Requests (Name,Mail,Betreff,Message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$betreff', '$message')");
```

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

---

Since you are just beginning to get into coding:

Here are a few tutorials on prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

Comment: the tutorials that you posted, are about mysqli_* or?
mysqli_* syntax and mysql_* syntax are different or?

Comment: Yes for `mysqli_*` and the others are PDO just under that. `mysqli` is a newer version of MySQL. If you're going to use it, you can't mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` and some of the DB connection parameters are used slightly differently. @Nico

Comment: ok thank you!
and can you say me what PDO is, in a simply way? :)

Comment: You're welcome @Nico In short *"PDO - PHP Data Objects - is a database access layer providing a uniform method of access to multiple databases."* Taken from this page http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059 Plus, this page http://stackoverflow.com/q/2190737/ will explain it better. See it on PHP.net as well http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: thank you :)
i will read this in further time
what you use? PDO or mysqli_* to access on a database?

Comment: You're welcome @Nico I use a mix of both APIs, since some of the servers I work with do not have PDO available due to older versions of PHP, so I'm forced to use `mysqli_*` functions on some of them. I rather work with PDO exclusively, but that is often not the case; one must work with what one has been given to work with ;-) Cheers and enjoy the adventure!

Answer (score 0):

DON'T USE that code. It's quite old. Try with pdo, as mine, or other.

Why do you use the sendContact() action on javascript? that's not php. Are you using ajax, so? If not, you must know that on click refers to js not to php.

I don't know what you did, but here's an example of PHP code you can use to insert the data in the database.

```
<?php /*insert.php*/
try {
$database_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. $dbhost .';dbname='. $dbname . ';charset=utf8', $dbuser, DB_PASS);
}   catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
}

$database_connection->prepare("INSERT into db_name (add, ghj, qwe) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3"); //and so on

$database_connection->bind(":value1", $value, PDO::PARAM_vartype); //vartype is the variable type (integer-int...)
```

/*do the rest of values*/

```
$database_connection->execute();

?>
```

Comment: the sendContact() is a js function what we used before we included the .php file, does it go in conflict with the .php code?

Comment: No, but when you submit the form it directly calls that file, action="whateverthenameis.php". If it is for that, you don't need it. But if it performs other action, you obviously have to leave it, :)

Comment: what i wrote is fine within your data. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most likely in this line

```
$sql_befehl = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Contact_Requests (Name,Mail,Betreff,Message) VALUES ($name, $email, $betreff, $message");
```

It should be

```
$sql_befehl = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Contact_Requests (Name,Mail,Betreff,Message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$betreff', '$message')");
```