# UTF-8 encoding in a database class

Tags: php, sql, oop

I have a database class but when I use it values from the database are printed without polish chars :(

```
Gra�yna
```

it should be

```
Grażyna
```

In mysql database Collation is utf8_polish_ci

How can I solve this problem?

```
    <?php 

class Baza {

    private $link;
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->database    = $database;

        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("Problem z połączeniem z bazą.");

        mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link)
            OR die("Problem z wyborem bazy.");

        return true;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Niepoprawne zapytanie: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->link)
            OR die("Problem z odłączeniem się!");
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SET NAMES utf8`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql) after connecting and [utf-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) text files for your code and `content-type: x; charset=utf-8` [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php) and [request](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/YmBuSfRHoN4) headers even with [ajax](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=655370&start=0).

Btw. your should really [use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead of your current mysql driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo).

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Stop using `mysql_*` it's deprecated, switch to PDO.

**Answer**

Use [mysql_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to set proper encoding.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8')
```

In your case

```
$this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("Problem z połączeniem z bazą.");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $this->link)
```

Comment: Thanks but where exactly should I put this?