# Inserting value in a JavaScript variable from php code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to test the following code for inserting the value from PHP code to my javascript variable x

tested the PHP code, and it's giving the correct output but the alert box in the javascript shows this -

> date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) and activity=1 group by code having b > 1000"; $query = mysql_query($myquery); if ( ! $myquery ) { echo mysql_error(); die; } $data = array(); for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) { $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);  } //echo json_encode($data); echo ''; mysql_close($server); ?>

```html
<html>
  <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing </title>
   
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    $username='user'; 
    $password='pass';   
    $host='xx.xx.xx.xx';
    $database='abc';
    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
    $myquery = 'select code a,sum(fee) b from xyz where date > date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) and activity=1 group by code having b > 1000';
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);
    if ( ! $myquery ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }
    $data = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);    
    }
    //echo json_encode($data);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="myPhpValue" value="'. json_encode($data) . '">';
    
    mysql_close($server);
    ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
             var x = document.getElementById("myPhpValue").value;
             alert(x);  
        }
        test();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're inserting a value into html, not javascript code. so use `htmlspecialchars` instead of `json_encode`

Comment: i am inserting the value in a javascript variable.. and i tried a ssuggested, it isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="myPhpValue" value="'. json_encode($data) . '">';
```

Then:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myPhpValue").value;
```

you need to insert `id="myPhpValue"`, because you used the `"getElementById";`

Answer (score 0):

Add ID attribute in the html line

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="myPhpValue" value="'. json_encode($data) . '">';
```

replace the above line by

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="myPhpValue" id ="myPhpValue" value="'. json_encode($data) . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a value into html, not javascript code.
Do it like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
 var x = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
 alert(x);  
}
test();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Server configuration problems

If You are getting php code on client-side (view-source to confirm), then the PHP engine is not working on the server.
You should check that php is properly installed on the server and is set as a handler for php files in your web server.
This depends on your web server and operating system.

---

### Code problems

Problem #1: your output (echo) is creating an HTML element, not javascript. Hence you should escape the content for HTML - use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead of [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)

Problem #2: you access the element with javascript [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) but your actual element does not have an ID. Hence need to add the id attribute to your html input element.

---

Solution:

Stage 1: php outputs html - use `htmlspecialchars` and add **id** attribute

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="myPhpValue" id="myPhpValue" value="'. htmlspecialchars($data) . '">';
```

Stage 2: javascript accesses html element (this is taken as-is from your code).

```
var x = document.getElementById("myPhpValue").value;
```

---

### Side-note

You're using a [**deprecated**](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) [`mysql`](http://php.net/mysql) extension and should switch to [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

There are numerous discussions both on SO and external resources on the matter.

Just a few:

- [Choosing an API - PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)
- [What is the difference between MySQL, MySQLi and PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo)
- [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)